# Changing/reverting Samsung's "Recent tabs" color theme to Nougat (based on app's theme) on Oreo device

Tags: samsung, 8.0-oreo, themes, recents-screen

On Samsung devices running on Android 7.0 Nougat, the recent tabs have different colors based on the apps' theme. On Android 8.0 Oreo, they are all the same color.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

I want to find a way to revert to the Nougat version. I plan to install Magisk, but rootless solutions are preferred.

Comment: I remember this same exact question a few days ago, but cannot find it to reference it as a duplicate. Did you delete, and re-submit this to place it at the top of the queue?

Comment: Related: [How to get back colored app headers in recent apps list?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203796) (with an informative answer, but not the fix)