# How to get back colored app headers in recent apps list on Samsung devices running on Android Oreo?

Tags: samsung, 8.0-oreo, themes, recents-screen

Before, in [recent apps list](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=android%20recent%20apps) of my phone (Samsung Galaxy Note8), headers of apps were colored.  Now, they are all white.

I am not sure whether it was caused by the transition from Nougat (7.1) to Oreo (8.0) or by a change in some Android settings. They are white for several months.

I would like to return to colored ones for faster navigation using app colors. Is it possible?

Comment: Related: [Changing/reverting Samsung's “Recent tabs” color theme to Nougat (based on app's theme) on Oreo device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/197164) (not yet answered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that this is not possible, because Oreo re-used the color coding for different purpose:

- **white header:** standard app

  - and here, the original coloring concept is partially present in **text color** (instead of bg color)
- **light cyan header:** app pair on split screen

[image]

I think that this new coloring purpose implies that the original coloring is gone.